# Allocating memory which its physical address size will be 32bit

Tags: linux-kernel, 32-bit, memory-address

I have a PCI device that takes 32bit physical address as a parameter, How do I allocate memory (in the kernel) which its physical address size will be 32bit.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need it for DMA? Something else? Please, elaborate. (There are few ways how to achieve something similar depending on the answers to above questions)

Comment: Yes, for DMA, I'm writing directly to the registers through PCI MMIO, a few registers require 32bit physical address.

Comment: Use either DMA mapping API against kmalloced memory, or allocate with *dma_alloc_coherent()*. In both cases be sure that device, that does DMA, has proper DMA mask setting.